# Как перенести таблицы БД MySQL через PMA?

Tags: phpmyadmin, php, mysql

Я сейчас переношу сайт на другой хостинг и нужно перенести БД. На стаорм экспортирую БД, а на новом она не импортируется, ибо там прописано создать такую же БД, и там таблички всякие и т.п. А мне никаких БД создавать не нужно. Только таблицы вставить..

Comment: где "там" прописано? В файле .sql ?

Comment: Да, в забекапенном файле

Comment: Экспорт через phpmyadmin?

Comment: Да, через него

Comment: И какая ошибка при импорте?

Comment: CREATE DATABASE  `p70012_base` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;


Ответ MySQL: 

#1044 - Access denied for user 'inferusvv_crm'@'localhost' to database 'p70012_base'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для того, чтобы экспортировать не всю БД целиком, а только ее таблицы, в PMA предварительно выберите целевую таблицу, потом сделайте экспорт (нужно будет выбрать нужные таблицы для экспорта).

На новом сервере, так же, сначала зайдите в нужную БД, а там уже делайте импорт.

Сабо собой разумеется, что на новом сервере предварительно нужно будет удалить(или переименовать) таблицы, имена которых совпадают с таблицами на тестовом.

Удачи.

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего Ваш пользователь не имеет права создавать несколько баз данных на сервере. т.е. импортировать нужно в уже существующую БД
Вам нужно:
 1. Зайти на локальной машине в phpmyadmin.
 2. Выбрать нужную базу
 3. сделать экспорт и получить файл вида

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 3.4.11.1deb1
-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
--
-- Host: localhost
-- Generation Time: Feb 08, 2013 at 01:50 PM
-- Server version: 5.5.29
-- PHP Version: 5.4.6-1ubuntu1.1

SET SQL_MODE="NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";

/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;

--
-- Database: `barada`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `storeactions`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `storeactions` (
  `aid` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Primary Key: Unique actions ID.',
  `type` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'The object that that action acts on (node, user, comment, system or custom types.)',
  `callback` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'The callback function that executes when the action runs.',
  `parameters` longblob NOT NULL COMMENT 'Parameters to be passed to the callback function.',
  `label` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Label of the action.',
  PRIMARY KEY (`aid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Stores action information.';

--
-- Dumping data for table `storeactions`
--
```

Потом на хостинге войти в уже существующую базу данных и сделать импорт ранее созданного файла, должно все работать.

P.S. Если база от Drupal то нужно чистить все таблицы с кэшем, иначе будут проблемы при импорте.